# Bean Validation on Jax-RS Resource stops working while using CDI on Apache TomEE 8.0.10

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, bean-validation, apache-tomee

I'm having troubles getting bean validation to work with the following minimalised project consisting only of this three java files plus pom.xml. I'm using Apache TomEE 8.0.10.

LoginMessage.java

```
package org.example;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class LoginMessage {

    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;
}
```

SessionService.java

```
package org.example;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Log
@RequestScoped
public class SessionService {

    public void login(final LoginMessage loginMessage) {
        log.info(loginMessage.toString());
    }
}
```

SessionController.java

```
package org.example;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Log
@Path("/session")
public class SessionController {

    @Inject
    private SessionService sessionService;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void postLoginMessage(@Valid final LoginMessage loginMessage) {
        sessionService.login(loginMessage);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>beanval</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you post an empty JSON object it ignores the `@Valid` annotation in SessionController#postLoginMessage() and directly outputs the log message containing the toString() content of the LoginMessage object through SessionService#login() method.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/beanval-1.0-SNAPSHOT/session
Content-Type: application/json

{
}
```

```
13-Mar-2022 01:30:39.700 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-6] SessionService.login LoginMessage(username=null, password=null)
```

If you remove or comment out the `@RequestScoped` annotation from SessionService and post the empty JSON-Object after restart of TomEE then bean validation works and logs:

```
13-Mar-2022 01:52:51.594 WARNUNG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper.toResponse Value (null) of SessionController.postLoginMessage.arg0.password: must not be blank
13-Mar-2022 01:52:51.595 WARNUNG [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationExceptionMapper.toResponse Value (null) of SessionController.postLoginMessage.arg0.username: must not be blank
```

I would like to use CDI in combination with Bean-Validation in JAX-RS Resource.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was to give a complement for asking a question in a way that is concise and clear.

Comment: What happens if you use @ApplicationScoped instead of @RequestScoped?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher thank you. It is the same with `@ApplicationScoped` and also with `@Stateless`

Comment: I now also tried it with `@SessionScoped` with same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all to come up to some kind of a solution I will stop using bean validation at controller layer. It works at service layer and so I can continue to work on my web app.

The solution is using the `@Valid` annotation in SessionService#login() method and remove it from SessionController#postLoginMessage() method.

If it is really a bug in TomEE the alternative could also be to use another application server until it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in OpenWebBeans or TomEE. So what's happening is the first the actual instance of the bean is managed by JAX-RS, and the second, the bean is managed by the CDI container. In the second case, there needs to be some sort of interceptor the invokes the Bean Validation framework.

I would start a discussion on the mailing list and open a bug on in the JIRA. If you can create a sample project that reproduces the problem it helps the devs out tremendously.

As a workaround, you can `@Inject private Validator validator` and if there are any constraint violations returned, `throw new  ConstraintViolationException(constraintViolations);`.

Comment: Fully agree - example code + mail via dev@tomee.apache.org would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Also, we tested this internally, it it looks like it only affects JSON payloads which is sort of interesting

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher I cannot reproduce this. I now have tried it with `application/xml` and changed payload to `<loginMessage/>`. This results in same behavior as with json.

Comment: @rzo1 the code above is a complete working example feel free to submit it to the mentioned email address.

Comment: miracles-whip it's up to you to submit :) Open source depends on community members like you submitting well thought out examples like you did above. Tell you what, you can skip the mailing list, but log a bug here with your code attached! https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TOMEE/issues/TOMEE-2800?filter=allopenissues

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher I respect your opinion about how you see how open source works. For me it is different. If someone is really committed, then she will do anything to push it. For different reasons I am not that person and further discussion about this topic would be another question on one of the other sites of SO.